# how can I split monthly data to weekly and keep existing data?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I want to split monthly data to weekly and fill each week row with the same monthly value for which each week refers to.

These variables are the ones that I need to work with.
"starting date"  non-null datetime64[ns]
"ending date" non-null datetime64[ns]

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("file")
import pandas as pd
import math, datetime
d1 = datetime.date(yyyy, mm, dd)

d2 = datetime.date(yyyy, mm, dd)
h = []
while d1 <= d2: 
    print(d1) 
    d1 = d1 + datetime.timedelta(days=7) 

    h.append(d1)

df = pd.Series(h)
print(df)
```

I have tried the code above but 
I think It is completly useless:

This is what I have in my dataset:

```
price    starting date  ending date   model
 1000     2013-01-01  2013-01-14       blue
 598      2013-01-01  2013-01-14       blue
 156      2013-01-15  2013-01-28       red
```

This is what I would like to get:

```
weekly date       price    model
 2013-01-01        1000    blue
 2013-01-01        598     blue
 2013-01-08        1000    blue
 2013-01-08        598     blue
 2013-01-15        156     red
 2013-01-22        156     red
```

Comment: Your words and your example are different. You you have monthly data or bi-monthly data that you want to convert to weekly data? Also, we don't know what your edge cases might be. Are there instances from the original data where the starting and ending dates might overlap?

Comment: If the data is biweekly as shown, Please refer to the below answer

Comment: actually the data is not biweekly. i want to merge the interval between starting date and ending date and get it per week.

Comment: Polkaguy6000.  You  have monthly data or bi-monthly data that you want to convert to weekly data? yes, this is what I want. But i have a 500 observations and 15 columns. For instance, from 2013-01-01 to  2013-01-14 there are two weeks right.Well, I want a new column by weeks with two rows with the same value as both  from 2013-01-01 to  2013-01-07 and 2013-01-08 to  2013-01-14 have same value.

Comment: @miguelmedina so 14 columns are date and 1 with data? does my answer work for you?

Comment: anky_91 No, the other way around. 2  columns are date, which I want to split them into one single weekly column, and 13 columns are data. So summarizing, 13 data and 2 date.

Comment: @miguelmedina cant think how would it be, can you post 3-4 columns of data as well as a sample

Comment: anky_91 hi, I have updated my existing date in the main question. Please have a look on it, you might be able to see what I am looking for. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Something like below:

*Convert to `pd.to_datetime()`*

```
df[['starting date','ending date']] = df[['starting date','ending date']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

*Create a dictionary from the `start time` column:*

```
d=dict(zip(df['starting date'],df.data))
#{Timestamp('2013-01-01 00:00:00'): 20, Timestamp('2013-01-15 00:00:00'): 21}
```

*Using `pd.date_range()` create a dataframe having weekly intervals of the start time:*

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(df['starting date'].iloc[0],df['ending date'].iloc[-1],freq='W-TUE'),columns=['StartDate'])
```

*Same for end time:*

```
df_new['EndDate']=pd.date_range(df['starting date'].iloc[0],df['ending date'].iloc[-1],freq='W-MON')
```

*Map the `data` column based on start time and `ffill()` till the next `start time` arrives:*

```
df_new['data']=df_new.StartDate.map(d).ffill()
print(df_new)

   StartDate    EndDate  data
0 2013-01-01 2013-01-07  20.0
1 2013-01-08 2013-01-14  20.0
2 2013-01-15 2013-01-21  21.0
3 2013-01-22 2013-01-28  21.0
```

Comment: Question about this method. Not sure if performance is a factor, but for my future reference, is `map` vectorized in this context. My answer uses a merge instead. Not sure which would be faster, and I don't have a big enough dataset to test it.

Comment: Yes since map is a pandas method, it's vectorized and should be fast enough

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make an assumption that the `starting date` and the `ending date` never overlap in your dataset. I'm also going to assume that your example is correct because it contradicts your words. It's not monthly data, but rather bi-monthly data. This code should work with any frequency.

```
 # creates some sample data
 df = pd.DataFrame(data={'starting date':pd.to_datetime(['2019-01-01','2019-01-15','2019-02-01','2019-02-15']),
                                 'data':[1,2,3,4]})

 # Hold the stant and end dates of the new df
 d1 = pd.datetime(2019,1,1)
 d2 = pd.datetime(2019,2,28)

 # Create a new DF to hold results
 new_df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.DatetimeIndex(start=d1,end=d2,freq='w')})

 # Merge based on the closest start date.
 result = pd.merge_asof(new_df,df,left_on='date',right_on='starting date')
```

Comment: P.S. This also assumes that `starting date` is a datetime if not, you'll have to convert it using `pd.to_datetime()` like the other answer suggests.